# Two lines intersecting

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm very confused by studying a book on linear algebra. The task couldn't be more simple:

Line P is described by the following two points:

P1=(1,0,1) and P2=(1,1,1)

Line Q is described by the following two points:

Q1=(0,1,0) and Q2=(1,2,1)

We need to find the point of intersection between those two lines, which I calculated to be (-2,-3,-2).

The solution in the book is given to be (1,2,1):

[image]
[image]

Is that just a plain error or am I missing something?

The reason I thought my solution was right:

Any point on line P can be described by the following equation:

$(1,0,1)+x(1,1,1)$. If I set $x = -3$, then we can reach (-2,-3,-2),

as $1-3=-2$, $0-3=-3$, $1-3=-2$.

Any point on line Q can be described by the following equation:

$(0,1,0)+y(1,2,1)$. If I set $y = -2$, then we can reach (-2,-3,-2),

as $0-2=-2$, $1-4=-3$, $0-2=-2$.

Thus, $(-2,-3,-2)$ is a point both lines have in common and thus a point of intersection.

Can you help me spot my mistake?

Comment: How did you get your solution?

Comment: I constructed the equations for x,y,z for both lines and equated them with each other (sorry, my english is rather bad for discussing mathematics)

Comment: @Fang Can you please write your solution step-by-step? After you write it all out, you might even spot your own mistake! By the way, it doesn't matter if your English is bad here, since maths is supposed to be a universal language.

Comment: Actually see my mistake now -_- Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the System
$$1=t$$
$$s=1+t$$
$$1=t$$ 
so we get

$$s=2$$ and our intersection point is given by $$[1;2;1]$$

Answer (score 2):

> Any point on line P can be described by the following equation: $(1,0,1)+x(1,1,1)$.

This is not correct because the line contains the points $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,1).$ Note that $(1,1,1)$ is a point and not a vector. One vector that gives you the direction of the line is $(1,1,1)-(1,0,1)=(0,1,0).$ Now the line can be described by the equation

$$(1,0,1)+x(0,1,0).$$

There is a similar mistake with the other line. It is given $$(0,1,0)+y(1,1,1).$$

Now you can get the solution.